# Disable "Messages from Firefox" on new tab page

Tags: firefox

This annoying bit at the bottom of the page:

[image]

It's a new message every time.

Why disable? It steals your attention. It's distracting.

Comment: Are you sure you have a legitimate version of Firefox? I've never seen that message. Does it appear when started in Safe mode, without add-ons?

Comment: They're shoving obnoxious SJW political rhetoric in there too now.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

1. In the address bar, go to `about:preferences#home`
2. Uncheck the `Snippets` checkbox:
   [image]